# Using XGBoost with Java

Tags: java, python, xgboost

I have seen that you can use XGBoost with Java using XGBoost4J (here are some example codes: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-example). But is it possible to train an XGBoost model using Python and then using the wrapper to call the same model object on the Java side for prediction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple implementations that do that. For example this [pure java xgboost predictor](https://github.com/komiya-atsushi/xgboost-predictor-java) or the one you mentioned.
You have to save the trained model in python, and then you are able to to load that file and use it in java.